# How to call $addToSet if an array exists if it doesnt then call $set in one query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey so I am trying to set a new array that does not exist in the mongodb docs, but I want to be able to throw additional documents into the array without constantly replacing the values.

for example:

```
users {
    id: 'value1',
    name: {value2},
    friends: [
               {friendID: 'value x', type: 'valuey', TAGS: [tag1, tag2]}

             ]
```

Basically TAGS does not exist and I want to create it and add tag1, and if it does exist I want to just add tag2 to the array...

This is to make sense of the variables in the sample above to what I have in my db:

```
friendStatus = friends,
fuId = friendID,
labels = TAGS
```

Here is my attempt:

```
Friend.findOneAndUpdate({userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.signedCookies.userid), 
'friendStatus.fuId': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user)}, 
{$addToSet: {'friendStatus.$.labels': req.body.labelNew}}
    , function(err, userX) {    


}
```

Comment: It seems like your fields are named incorrectly so the query doesn't match the sample document you provided. Please try just running the query to make sure that works before you try the update.

Comment: Hey yeah, the query works if the array exists, otherwise I need to call $set... friendStatus is (friends) in the sample top doc, and labels is (TAGS), fuId being (id)...I have it working if I run it with $set first creating the array then changing it to $addToSet (since at that point the array exists.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do what you want with the MongoDB update syntax.

Here is a feature which would allow something like that: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6566

Answer (score -2):

You should make use of the "upsert" flag:

Friend.update({userId: req.signedCookies.userid, 'friendStatus.fuId': req.body.favourites}, {$addToSet: {'friendStatus.$.labels': req.body.labelNew}}, {upsert:true}, function(err, item) { ... })

However, 'friendStatus.$.labels' is saying "I have multiple friendStatuses, and I want this operation to apply to any/all of them for which my query matches' (at least, afaict) -- So I'm not positive this will work right for you. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/ (See also the upsert flag at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/)

Comment: That will not work as you can't mix the positional operator ($) with upsert as it had nothing to replace the '$' with on insert, so you get a field named '$'.

Comment: Yeah, as I said (on IRC at least), the positional operator messes with it a bit, but it is the way to do what he needs to do. I think a better solution would involve avoiding the positional operator, since it doesn't actually seem appropriate here. Appropriate would be to operate on the subdocument that he's actually looking for.

However the question here is really "How do I use $addToSet for an array field which does not exist yet?" and the answer to that is upsert.